# How to effectively use iNotify with rSyslog caching?

Tags: caching, logging, syslog, inotify

By default, rsyslog doesn't sync data to log file immediately for performance reasons. 
Ref to section [Output File Syncing](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v3compatibility.html)

Does that mean that there could be a scenario where if I am using iNotify on syslog files, I may miss an event?

So far, I am monitoring files using tail -f and it seems to be catching all the events. But I am paranoid that syslog caching may lead to inotify events being missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and created this- http://code.google.com/p/logmon/ as per @cpugeniusmv suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you're doing when you receive an inotify event. If you're keeping track of the last offset, reading to EOF on a new event, and updating the offset, you should be fine (that's what tail does, except it uses a timer instead of inotify (well, new ones may use inotify)).

Comment: My concern is that if I am going to miss any event at first place. If syslog is caching, it may not touch log file at all- if that happens, inotify won't see any event.

Comment: Sure, there may be a delay depending on how long rsyslogd buffers lines, but I wouldn't expect it would be a very long delay. You just wouldn't be guaranteed an inotify event per line written to the log file.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to make it happen? I need guaranteed event processing. I am now thinking of exploring syslog plugins

Comment: You can turn off the rsyslog caching with `$ActionFileEnableSync on`. Would that suffice?

Comment: that might, but according to rsyslog documentation, there could be drop of 50% in performance. I will run some tests to see what is the real drop in performance.

Comment: That's correct. That option causes rsyslogd to write each line to the file as it gets it and perform a sync to disk. So if there is any other substantial writing/reading to/from disk going on, this is going to probably slow it down.

Comment: The other thing you might look into is writing something that can accept syslog events via some sort of socket so you don't have to touch the disk. It looks like rsyslog will support forwarding to all sorts of TCP, Unix, and UDP sockets. I'd avoid UDP due to the potential for a lost event.

Comment: Thanks! I created http://code.google.com/p/logmon/ as per @cpugeniusmv  suggestion